# Why are my three.js and paper.js scripts conflicting?

Tags: javascript, three.js, paperjs

I am trying to create a color picker for a three.js sketch and am attempting to use paper.js to carry this out, placing each part in a separate element.

Both my scripts work individually but when I put them together only the three.js appears to be rendered.

I've commented out various lines of code and as soon as I append the renderer to my div it prevents the paper.js part from rendering.

How can I render both elements?

[Link to the pastebin code](http://pastebin.com/Zvv0k5nA)

Comment: Are you using the same canvas element for both libs?

Comment: Um I don't think so but err maybe! I don't actually define a canvas element for the three.js, just a renderer which I append to the body of a div in my page.